# rsync: Use filters to exclude top-level directory but include some of its subdirectories

Tags: linux, rsync, filter

I want to back up my `/home` directory with **rsync**. I have read rsync's [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) and decided to use filter rules for this task.

What I would like to achieve:  **Exclude all files and directories in the `Repos` directory but keep all `pull_all.sh` files and `output` directories** --- regardless where they are located within the `Repos` directory.

So far, I have ended up with following filter list, but this backs up only the `pull_all.sh` files but not the `output` directories:

```
# Files prefixed with "+ " are included. Files prefixed with "- " are excluded.
#
# The order of included and excluded files matters! For instance, if a folder
# is excluded first, no subdirectory can be included anymore. Therefore,
# mention included files first. Then, mention excluded files.
#
# See section "FILTER RULES" of rsync manual for more details.


# Included Files

# TODO: This rules do not work properly!
+ output/***
+ pull_all.sh
- Repos/**

# Excluded Files

- .android
- .cache
...
```

I use the filter list in my script `run_rsync.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

date="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
hostname="$(hostname)"

# debug_mode="" # to disable debug mode
debug_mode="--list-only"

# Note: With trailing "/" at source directory, source directory is not created at destination.
rsync ${debug_mode} --archive --delete --human-readable --filter="merge ${hostname}.rsync.filters" --log-file=logfiles/$date-$hostname-home.log --verbose /home backup/
```

Unfortunately, the existing StackExchange threads have not solved my problems:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270519/rsync-exclude-a-directory-but-include-a-subdirectory
- [Using Rsync include and exclude options to include directory and subdirectory but exlude files in subdirectory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289923/using-rsync-include-and-exclude-options-to-include-directory-and-subdirectory-bu)

What's going wrong here?

**[Update] Here is an example how the home directory looks like and which files to keep and which files to ignore:**

```
user@hostname:~$ tree /home/ | head
/home/
└── user
    ├── Desktop                -> keep this
    │   ├── file1              -> keep this
    │   └── file2              -> keep this
    ├── Documents              -> keep this
    ├── Repos
    │   ├── pull_all.sh        -> keep this
        ├── subdir1
        │   ├── output         -> keep this
        ├── subdir2
            ├── another_subdir
                ├── output     -> keep this
        ├── subdir3            -> do not keep (because does not contain any "output")
        ├── file3              -> do not keep
```

Comment: Also take a look at [Bash scripting and rsync: how to include just some folders and subfolders...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503094/100397)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slightly restating what I've interpreted as your requirements,

- Include all `pull_all.sh` files regardless of where we find them
- Include all `output` directories *and their contents* regardless of where we find them
- Exclude the `Repos` directory, other than what we have already stated
- Include everything else

This can be specified as follows

```
rsync --dry-run --prune-empty-dirs -av

    --include 'pull_all.sh'
    --include 'Repos/**/output/***'

    --include '*/'

    --exclude 'Repos/***'

    /home backup/
```

Some notes

- The `--include '*/'` is required so that `rsync` will consider heading down into the `Repos` directory tree (to look for `pull_all.sh` files), which would otherwise be excluded by the final `--exclude` statement.
- The three different uses of `*` are different:

  - `*` matches anything except `/` characters
  - `**` matches anything including `/` characters
  - `dir/***` is a shortcut equivalent to specifying `dir/` and `dir/**`.
- The `--prune-empty-dirs` flag stops `rsync` creating empty directories, which is particularly important as we need to process the `Repos` directory tree looking for `pull_all.sh` and `output` items.
- Remove `--dry-run` when you are happy with the results.

Comment: I have updated my answer to address your revised question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) The updated answer works like a charm. I guess the key was to add `--include '*/'`. Otherwise, **rsync** would not have traversed the `Repos` directory.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I've added some notes that I hope make it clearer what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "+" for the wanted sub directory and "-" for the rest:

```
rsync -auv "${src}" "${dst}" \
--filter=+_"/parent-dir/to-sync-child-dir/" \
--filter=-_"/parent-dir/*"
```

Comment: The OP already had `+` and `-` rules in their question, using a filter rules file rather than arguments on the command. The problem was that they couldn't get a combination to achieve their required set of files to be copied. I don't see how a generic answer with `src`, `dst`, `parent_dir`, etc. addresses the question that was asked. You would need to rewrite your answer to show how to apply filter rules to the situation