# rsync exclude AppData but include Firefox bookmarks?

Tags: rsync, cygwin

I want to backup my Windows home directory using cygwin and rsync:

```
rsync.exe -vrt --delete --exclude=AppData "/cygdrive/C/Users/user1/" "/cygdrive/D/backup/"
```

As you can see I excluded the *AppData* directory.

Is it possible to include my Firefox bookmarks in the following path?

```
AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/*/places.sqlite
```

The asterisk stands for a the profile name. It's not known because Firefox generates random names there.

Maybe it's possible using an exclude script with --exclude-from?

I know it's possible to copy the *places.sqlite* to another folder using power shell and then backup this folder.

But maybe it's possible directly with rsync.

Comment: Have you tried explicitally including your Firefox bookmarks? `rsync.exe -vrptlH --delete --exclude=AppData --include=AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profile/*/places.sqlite "/cygdrive/C/Users/user1/" "/cygdrive/D/backup/"`

Comment: This does not work. If you exclude "AppData" it won't enter the folder.

Comment: Try adding a trailing / at the end of include pattern and it'll work: `rsync.exe -vrptlH --delete --exclude=AppData/ --include=AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profile/*/places.sqlite/ "/cygdrive/C/Users/user1/" "/cygdrive/D/backup/"`

Comment: No, it's still not working (same cause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a include.txt file with this content:

```
+ AppData/Roaming
+ AppData/Roaming/Mozilla
+ AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox
+ AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles
+ AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/*/places.sqlite
- AppData/*
- AppData/Roaming/*
- AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/*
- AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/*
- AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/*/*
```

Then use it in rsync with the parameter --include-from=include.txt

This solution does not need --prune-empty-dirs so you can also backup empty directories. Also there's no need to create a link.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty much a duplicate of [rsync: Use filters to exclude top-level directory but include some of its subdirectories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503295/100397).

You need to include the `AppData` folder tree for searching to that you can find `places.sqlite`, but exclude everything except that file.

```
rsync --dry-run -av --prune-empty-dirs \
    --include '/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/*/places.sqlite' \
    --include '*/' \
    --exclude '/AppData/***' \
    '/cygdrive/C/Users/user1/' '/cygdrive/D/backup/'
```

The `--prune-empty-dirs` stops the destination being filled with directories that would otherwise remain empty, so that `rsync` creates only the directories it needs to hold the files it's copying. (It's a little strange that this isn't the default action, but it isn't.)

On my system, `places.sqlite` was under `Profiles/*` rather than `Profile/*` so I've adjusted my suggested command accordingly. As you might expect, remove `--dry-run` when you're happy with the result.

Comment: It does not work. It includes AppData/Local for example.

Comment: I did not use --prune-empty-dirs. Did not know this is necessary...

Comment: @somega if this answer (or the other one) worked for you, please accept it with the tick mark beside the voting buttons

Answer (score 1):

here is another decision, to make symlinks:
move places.sqlite to somewhere in rsync include range, like c:\places\*\places.sqlite

```
mklink c:\places\*\places.sqlite AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profile\*\places.sqlite
```

or even for directory, with syntax:

```
mklink /d <Link> <Target>
```

in result, rsync will copy all needed data, and skip other.